# Why i cant make the edge sharp

Tags: edges

Why my edge not sharp. I tried adding edge modifier. Bevel modifier, ctrl+e and made sharp, added crease of 1. In the tools the smooth and flat not giving the effect. In solid view it looks flat and edge but when press shift+z render view looks smooth. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

**Solid view**

[image]

**Render view (shift+z)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks okey..try to play around with a lighting..i believe correct lighting will produce a good edge as you wanted..

Comment: Will can u show me result with a good light and nothing else added

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a glossy effect on your material. It will also make these edges more visible. Try glossy shader.